# r does not allow the x axis to display the title (now with added data)

Tags: r, boxplot

The question was how to get `R` to display titles on the x- and y-axes when the plot is rotated. mtext was not allowing this to happen. The question then became how to do this with the data at hand.

Here is my edited code and data.

Small segment of my Data:

```
library(ggplot)
x <- structure(list(
CS1 = c(51.176802507837, 11.289327763008, 10.8584547767754, 5.37665764546685, 6.47159365761892), 
CS2 = c(34.9956506731101, 45.7147446193383, 23.788413903316, 42.4969135802469, 18.8998879103283), 
CS3 = c(3.59556251631428, 5.59228312932411, 11.7117536894149, 15.7240944017563, 9.72486977228754), 
CS4 = c(0.830633241559198, 2.57358541893362, 3.05352639873916, 7.01238591916558, 2.98276253547777), 
CS5 = c(6.6094547746612, 7.67873290538655, 9.93544994944388, 8.49609094535301, 6.71423210935406)), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now some code to make a ggplot.

```
xplot<-ggplot(x, aes(y = test, y = CS2, group = test))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(y = "Intensity",
       x = "Variable")+
  scale_x_discrete()

xplot
```

Comment: your edits removed your question.  Could you replace them so it's clear what you're asking (and doesn't require someone to fish through the edited history)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ggplot` from the `tidyverse`.

`<del>`It is useful to have a basic dataset to run from:`<\del>` Now that you have some data

```
library(tidyverse)
x <-structure(list(
CS1 = c(51.176802507837, 11.289327763008, 10.8584547767754, 5.37665764546685, 6.47159365761892), 
CS2 = c(34.9956506731101,  45.7147446193383, 23.788413903316, 42.4969135802469, 18.8998879103283), 
CS3 = c(3.59556251631428, 5.59228312932411, 11.7117536894149, 15.7240944017563, 9.72486977228754), 
CS4 = c(0.830633241559198, 2.57358541893362, 3.05352639873916,  7.01238591916558, 2.98276253547777), 
CS5 = c(6.6094547746612, 7.67873290538655, 9.93544994944388, 8.49609094535301, 6.71423210935406)), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

Now gather that data into two columns

```
x1 <- gather(x, test, values, CS1:CS5)
```

Now plot

```
xplot<-ggplot(x1, aes(x = test, y = values, group = test))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(y = "Intensity",
   x = "Variable")

xplot + coord_flip()
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help.
The box plots are on their side and with no labels?

Comment: Edited the answer to add a labels line for the individual . Obviously you will need to adapt this to your data set. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry to Bother you again, How is it that I copy a data set again from R? I think I'm going to ask the question in a different way

Comment: type `dput(<name of your file>)

Comment: Hi Bob, I have edited the question to reflect the issue I'm now having. If you have some time, feedback world be amazing!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I'm not getting the error "Error: Don't know how to add xplot to a plot"

Comment: Sorry - removed the `+` after the `x="variable")` part.

Comment: Last question I promise. Why does the gather function only go to 5 variables? I have more than one data set and I can't go any higher?

Comment: The function only goes to 5 because of the `CS1:CS5` command. Alter that bit to incorporate your other variables. If you leave that part empty (i.e. close brackets after `values`) then it will use all columns. Check the documentation for the calls (e.g. `?gather`) you are using, it helps and usually gives examples.